# Passing the Array with elements of Double data type to an API Procedure Using VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, double

nSamples here is 8192

```
'Get Data from Channel 1
Dim rgdSamples1() As Double
ReDim rgdSamples1(nSamples) As Double
Scope = AD2OsciFunc.AD2_FDwfAnalogInStatusData(hdwf, 0, rgdSamples1(nSamples), nSamples)
Scope = AD2OsciFunc.AD2_FDwfDeviceCloseAll()
```

How do I pass the array rgdSamples1 to the API function: *AD2_FDwfAnalogInStatusData*?

Comment: Without knowing anything does this work.. `AD2_FDwfAnalogInStatusData(rgdSamples1)` ?

Comment: I have already tested my code in VB.net and it seems that all APIs are working properly. Now, I'm trying to run it in VBA but I think VBA doesn't allow me to pass an array with double data type. The system crashes every time I try to run the program

Comment: When passing arrays to API functions you pass the first element in the array. EG `MyAPI(A(0))` API calls that take arrays have a count parameter.